# RVM + Ruby + Unable to install RVM ( Error : curl: (60) Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates )

Tags: ruby, rvm

While installing RVM to CentOS, I used https://rvm.io/rvm/install as reference.

First Command :

```
Install RVM stable with ruby:
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

But I am getting some strange error ie

```
curl: (60) Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle" of 
Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default bundle file 
isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in the bundle,
the certificate verification probably failed due to a problem with the 
certificate (it might be expired, or the name might not match the domain name in 
the URL).
```

Not able to install RVM. Any Idea ... Please share

Answer (score 0):

A *quick and dirty* way to get over this would be to use the `-k` or `--insecure` flag which means that you don't require any certificate verification.

IIRC certificates are installed as a different package in some distributions. I never used CentOS so I don't know the specifics.

Since the whole SSL scheme is extremely unreliable from a security perspective[1], I don't know what to make of this: In theory you should ONLY use websites that can ID themselves. In reality that would break a large chunk of the web, leaving the ones that are *theoretically secure* (not self-signed certs, etc.).

[1] [See Marlinspike's talk in BlackHat USA 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7Wl2FW2TcA) for an in depth overview of current SSL structure security flaws.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu I added the ~/.curlrc with the following content:

```
cacert = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
cert-type = PEM
```

Make sure, that cacert points to the correct path for your system.

Answer (score 0):

May be executing the following code before installing RVM will help:
`gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3`